# Unity3D strange behavior of cameras in multiplayer

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, multiplayer, photon

im new to unity and am struggling with a strange behavior of my Cameras.
Im programming an Online Multiplayer Game with Photon Plugin.

The strange behavior:

- Player1 logs in

  --> all good
- Player2 logs in

  --> Camera of Player1 switches to Player2 character

  --> Camera of Player2 switches to Player1 character​
- Player3 logs in

  --> Camera of Player 1 and Player2 switches to Player3 character

  --> Camera of Player3 switches to Player2 character.​

(But the movement-controll is working right for each player)

I got a Prefab of the character, which got a camera attached to itself in the inspector.

And here is my Code for initialization:

```c#
public class NetworkPlayer  : Photon.Pun.MonoBehaviourPun, Photon.Pun.IPunObservable
{
    public Animator anim;
    private Vector3 correctPlayerPos;
    private Quaternion correctPlayerRot;
    public GameObject myCam;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(photonView.IsMine)
        {
            Debug.Log("PhotonView.IsMine == true");
            //Kamera und Steuerung aktivieren
            myCam = GameObject.Find("Camera");
            myCam.SetActive(true);
            GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = true;
            Debug.Log("Steuerung und Cam aktiviert...");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(!photonView.IsMine)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, this.correctPlayerPos, Time.deltaTime*5);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, this.correctPlayerRot, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
    }

    //Exchange Position data
    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info){
        if(stream.IsWriting)
        {
            //Send data to others
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
            stream.SendNext(transform.rotation);
            stream.SendNext(anim.GetBool("Run"));
        } 
        else 
        {
            //Receive data from others
            this.correctPlayerPos = (Vector3) stream.ReceiveNext();
            this.correctPlayerRot = (Quaternion) stream.ReceiveNext();
            anim.SetBool("Run", (bool) stream.ReceiveNext());
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to attach the camera via the inspector instead of searching for it, like in the code sample above.
Hope anyone can help me with this :(

Thank you for your time!

Comment: GameObject.Find will search the current running scenes for a name match to the given string. Its not a reliable way to find a specific gameobject if there are multiple ones with the same name. You might want to see if this is the issue and in that case, find your camera in a different way.

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for your quick answer! I also tried to assign the camera directly in the Inspector. But that didn't solved the problem.

Comment: How do you mean assign it in the inspector?

Comment: I declared the variable GameObject myCam public and pulled the camera (which is attached to the player prefab) into the the script (which is also attached to the prefab).
I also deleted the GameObject.find command in the start method.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/njZA4Zh.png

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you do `SetAtive(true)` on the player but from your picture the Camera seems active by default anyway! So each new camera is added below the previous ones in the Hierachy which makes it the Camera rendered on top.

You can simply disable the `Camera` in the player prefab.

Anyway you should also actively disable the Camera for the other players in the script so you can't forget / don't have to rely on setting your prefab to a certain state

```c#
public class NetworkPlayer  : Photon.Pun.MonoBehaviourPun, Photon.Pun.IPunObservable
{
    public Animator anim;
    // you are referncing this for the prefab via the inspector
    // I would also use the proper type as a safety
    // this way you can't by accident reference something else here but a Camera
    public Camera myCam;

    // you should also this already via the inspector
    public PlayerMovement playerMovement;

    private Vector3 correctPlayerPos;
    private Quaternion correctPlayerRot;

    // Use Awake to gather components and references as fallback
    // if they where not referenced via the Inspector
    private void Awake()
    {
        FetchComponents();
    } 

    // Fetches components only if they where not referenced via the Inspector
    // this saves unnecessary GetComponent calls which are quite expensive
    //
    // + personal pro tip: By using the context menu you can now also in the Inspector simply click on FetchComponents
    // This way you 
    //   a) don't have to search and drag them in manually
    //   b) can already see if it would also work later on runtime 
    [ContextMenu(nameof(FetchComponents))]
    private void FetchComponents()
    {
        if(!playerMovement) playerMovement = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        if(!anim) anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        // Use GetComponnetInChildren to retrieve the component on yourself
        // or recursive any of your children!
        // Pass true in order to also get disabled or inactive ones
        if(!myCam) myCam = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>(true);
    }       

    // Now do your thing not only for the player but also actively disable the stuff
    // on all other players
    private void Start()
    {
        var isMine = photonView.IsMine;
        Debug.Log($"PhotonView.IsMine == {isMine}");
        // enable the cam for you, disable them for others!
        myCam.gameObject.SetActive(isMine);
        // enable controls for you, disable them for others
        playerMovement.enabled = isMine;

        Debug.Log($"Steuerung und Cam {isMine ? "" : "de"}aktiviert...");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey derHugo!
that solved my problem! I forgot to disable the camera in the prefab!
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sagíchdirnet Glad to help! Please feel free to mark the answer as excepted. I would still recommend to also use the script here so you don't depend on your prefab setup but actively apply one via script on runtime. This would avoid such "bugs" in the future ;)